# jQuery/AJAX on old Computers/Browsers

Tags: performance, jquery, cross-browser, user-friendly, browser-support

I am working on a plattform that will have a lot of users in the so called "developing countries". So many of them will be using old computers and old browsers in tiny internet cafes.

We want to make sure to give them a good user Experience and make sure the website loads as fast as possible.

Problem is, that while you can save a lot of requeasts and time, using jQuery/AJAX, it also brings along a lot of Problems:
- Will the Computers be powerfull enough to deal with the client side scripts?
- Will the old Browsers handle jQuery?

Does anyone have any experience with these sort of problems or might know of some sort of article on the topic?

Comment: Can you specify those "developing contries" a little closer. Depending on the country, the browser usage is very different. In China, for instance, there is [22%+ IE6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/). Did you do some research of the top browsers in your target countries?

Comment: @Michael: Good point. It will be used all over the world (hopefully). So the Browsers var from IE6 to Firefox 12.
Our current position is to keep the site as simple as possible so it runs in all areas, but i am unsure about weather or not IE6 might be able to do "some" jQuery/AJAX.

Comment: Yes, IE6 supports ajax, but JS performance is really bad in those old browsers, so keep that in mind and add "loading" dialogs to prevent too many clicks by waiting users.

Comment: @Michael, could you put that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the country, the browser usage is very different. In China, for instance, there is [22%+ IE6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/). When developing for old browsers, keep in mind that even if they support ajax and other fancy javascript stuff, they probably do it a lot slower than more modern browsers.

We did a comparison for a customer project some time ago. IE6, compared to a Firefox 4 was more than ten times slower in javascript execution speed, so we had to add a lot of tweaks (for instance do not add js click handlers on dom ready event, but on mouse over of each element seperately). It's also a good idea to show loading/waiting indicators to the user during expensive js tasks to prevent further clicking which will again cost performance.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpfull advise. Would you maybe know a good article on that as well?

Comment: No I don't, but we found out the major performance issues by measuring execution time for each separate feature. The best advice is only to improve functionalities you **know** to be slow (in contrast to you only **think** they are).